# Как работать с шириной и положением в потоке элементов с position: fixed?

Tags: html, css, width, fixed

Есть вот такой прототип сайта (смотреть лучше во весь экран):

```css
body {
 font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
 border-left: 1px solid silver;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
}

aside {
 background-color: silver;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
}

aside ul {
 margin: 0;
}

aside ul li {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 5px;
}

.main {
 background-color: gray;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#comp, #uslugi, #zakaz, #kontakt {
 height: 400px;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 20px 5px;
 background-color: silver;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron"><h1>Компания</h1></div>
   <aside class="col-md-3">
     <ul>
      <li>О компании</li>
      <li>Услуги</li>
      <li>Заказать</li>
      <li>Контакты</li>
    </ul>
   </aside>
   <div class="main col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
      <div id="comp">Здесь информация о компании</div>
     <div id="uslugi">Тут описание наших услуг</div>
     <div id="zakaz">В этом блоке можно оформить заказ</div>
     <div id="kontakt">Здесь - связаться с нами</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Задача - сделать так, чтоб скроллился только основной блок со всей информацией, а джумботрон и меню оставались на месте. Задаю для них position: fixed и получаю вот такую фигню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понятно, что с помощью <del>танцев с бубном</del> манипуляций с left, top, margin, z-index и т.д. можно добиться более-менее приемлемого расположения элементов на странице (хотя это очень похоже на "костыли", что плохо).

Но хуже всего то, что у зафиксированных элементов ломается ширина: у джумботрона она схлопывается, а у меню почему-то, наоборот, расширяется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задавать им принудительно какую-то ширину не хочется (тогда вообще теряется смысл использования сетки bootstrap, и для разных размеров экрана придётся вручную эту ширину подгонять).

Вопрос: есть ли какие-то способы работы с элементами с position: fixed, позволяющие сохранять их ширину и положение в потоке?

Comment: Что такое джумботрон?

Comment: класс в bootstrap. просто верхний блок (на суть вопроса это не влияет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это - задуманное поведение фиксированных блоков. Если вам требуется, чтобы эти блоки не вылезали за сетку, да и зарезервировать для них место на странице не помешало бы - можно попробовать делать два одинаковых блока.

Первый - с установленным `visibility: hidden`, он будет просто вычислять место. Второй - с установленным `position: fixed`, его надо будет скриптом разместить строго поверх первого.

Лучше всего первый блок изначально показывать, а скрывать скриптом - тогда страница будет корректно отображаться пока скрипт не запустится. И если. Второй блок можно создать тем же самым скриптом, чтобы не мучаться с версткой.

Получится как-то так:

```
$(".jumbotron, aside").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this), $copy = $this.clone().insertAfter($this);

  $this.css('visibility', 'hidden');
  $copy.css('position', 'fixed')
    .css('z-index', '1');

  setBounds();
  $(window).on('resize', setBounds);

  function setBounds() {
    var offset = $this.offset();
    $copy.css({
        left: offset.left,
        top: offset.top,
        width: $this.outerWidth(),
        height: $this.outerHeight(),
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: а что за setPosition?

Comment: @Grundy спасибо

Comment: @PavelMayorov, всё отлично работает, но есть один баг: когда проскролливаю страницу (до середины или до самого низа), а потом делаю рефреш, то зафиксированные элементы пропадают. сам не разобрался, как это поправить - может, вы подскажете?

Comment: @humster_spb мне не на чем по-экспериментировать :-) Попробуйте в разметке посмотреть что с ними случилось или в консоли ошибки поискать.

Comment: @humster_spb попробуйте еще один из вызовов offset заменить на position (ответ обновил), может в этом проблема...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не, так вообще всё сломалось (( Возвращайте offset обратно

Comment: @PavelMayorov и, кстати, не только с рефрешем такая проблема, но и просто с изменением размера окна... ошибок в консоли нет

Comment: @humster_spb видимо, jquery умный только в одну сторону... Попробуйте сделать вот так.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, теперь работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Интересно, когда же все браузеры допилят css-решение...

Answer (score 2):

Пока ещё для этого [слишком рано](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky), но всё же напишу такой ответ - вдруг когда пригодится:

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Это заголовок</h1>
  <p>
    Он всегда остаётся в верху страницы
    <br>
    <span style="color:red">Но только в Chrome 56+ и FF 32+</span>
  </p>
</header>

<section>
  <h1>А это - часть контента</h1>
  <p>Она скроллится под заголовком</p>
</section>

<section>
  <h1>Ещё контент</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum integer amet at <i>nulla mauris</i> sapien nulla, proin ligula elementum a auctor. Tellus sagittis, sed <a href="#">nam: sodales, quisque: eget</a> curabitur leo morbi urna. Sit curabitur ultricies congue, rutrum mattis quisque amet sed&nbsp;&mdash; congue tellus, sapien <b>nibh, at leo quam</b> at gravida et eget congue. Enim <b>nulla maecenas diam, adipiscing</b> ipsum <i>vulputate, vivamus in</i> diam curabitur, adipiscing, ornare enim et integer ut elementum urna. Duis tempus vitae massa ultricies metus non vitae adipiscing, metus non eros fusce. Diam&nbsp;&mdash; orci amet diam integer nibh&nbsp;&mdash; lectus porttitor, congue enim arcu tellus tempus, curabitur massa quam&nbsp;&mdash; sodales in eget. Nibh lectus, porttitor rutrum, congue orci sodales metus rutrum, <b>quisque vivamus.</b> Proin ultricies cursus pellentesque rutrum cursus massa <b>lorem sagittis ut</b> sodales.</p><p>Pharetra urna, eros sagittis <b>orci mauris auctor sapien lorem</b> malesuada porta congue lorem metus eros molestie nam leo, lorem: mattis sed. Pharetra&nbsp;&mdash; <a href="#">at, ultricies, sit mattis, porta eget</a> leo, sodales vitae metus ornare <b>diam duis ut lorem elementum</b> nulla nam. Ipsum arcu fusce, <i>auctor ornare</i> sodales pharetra quam duis, at. Integer molestie non nulla sodales sit morbi nibh tellus congue fusce enim&nbsp;&mdash; fusce non, ipsum malesuada porttitor at <b>eros. Sed</b> commodo arcu magna, congue lectus sed cursus <i>eu sem ligula lectus ligula arcu nam urna</i> integer, morbi maecenas.</p><p>In amet, a malesuada curabitur <a href="#">risus leo</a>, eros amet morbi curabitur sit: rutrum nam ultricies orci. In vitae justo nibh pellentesque curabitur vitae non sodales tempus congue donec in tellus orci porttitor adipiscing at quisque curabitur. Morbi tempus congue ornare diam&nbsp;&mdash; quam malesuada <a href="#">morbi arcu</a> ut&nbsp;&mdash; metus sem porta massa commodo duis eget curabitur auctor <a href="#">vivamus pellentesque enim</a> metus mauris morbi. Sodales lectus ornare lectus vitae enim pharetra nibh sem eget orci ultricies ut amet fusce mattis diam ligula vivamus et fusce eros curabitur. Sed urna curabitur, porta donec massa sagittis tellus non mauris, ligula risus: urna&nbsp;&mdash; lorem.</p><p>Vitae sem sed mattis quisque proin ligula enim arcu duis massa: sagittis orci ut. Lorem elementum integer curabitur proin donec molestie leo ornare quisque ornare ligula, proin donec eget risus, <a href="#">auctor lorem.</a> Pharetra nibh arcu commodo, adipiscing, quam pharetra porta molestie sapien, sagittis quisque curabitur at nam. Arcu <a href="#">ipsum eu orci sagittis nam</a> pharetra pellentesque sed: porttitor lorem ornare sit vivamus porta magna.</p><p>Eget duis lorem tempus pellentesque non mattis quisque, donec: justo donec ipsum, et lorem morbi leo <a href="#">a. Sem</a>: nam, <b>nibh nam justo in eget lorem, pharetra</b> fusce risus leo ultricies tellus integer arcu leo lorem.</p> 
</section>
```